# Loading images into a recycleview from a set folder

Tags: android, arrays, image, android-recyclerview

I am using a Recyclerview and want to add images in it which works fine. I want to use int array of drawables in my resource folder and load images from a set folder on my sdcard. I have a string array which lists paths of all images and sets a textview in my cardview but i can't convert that into an int array to load the images.

Here is my code, i have commented out the string array and int arrays that load the drawable.resources and textviews which are hardcoded.

If you need any more info/code then i can post it. Thanks in advance.

The feed.setMyFiles(previewsPath [i]); works fine.

The feed.setThumbnail(intarray[i]); is where im stuck.

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainCardActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

 private RecyclerView recyclerView;
 private CardView cardView;

 private ArrayList<FeedProperties> os_versions;
 private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
// private RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.maincardlayout);
    initContrls();
}

private void initContrls() {

    //cardView = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardList);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

   // final String[] versions = {"Synergy", "Synergy", "Synergy", "Synergy", "Synergy", "Synergy", "Synergy"};
   // final int[] previewsImages = {R.drawable.psss, R.drawable.psss, R.drawable.psss, R.drawable.psss, R.drawable.sss, R.drawable.dog, R.drawable.sss, R.drawable.psss, R.drawable.dog, R.drawable.dog, R.drawable.sss, R.drawable.psss};


    // Check for count
    os_versions = new ArrayList<FeedProperties>();

    File pathToFiles = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Overlays/Previews");

    String[] previewsPath = pathToFiles.list();

    //ArrayList<String> filePaths;
    //populate filePaths with your list of file paths.
    //feed.setThumbnail(Drawable.createFromPath(filePaths.get(i)));

    //int intarray[] = new int[previewsPath.length];


   // for (int i = 0; i < previewsPath.length; i++) {
       // FeedProperties feed = new FeedProperties();
        ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : pathToFiles.list()) {
            filePaths.add(s); }
        for (int i = 0; i < previewsPath.length; i++) {
            FeedProperties feed = new FeedProperties();
            feed.setThumbnail(Drawable.createFromPath(filePaths.get(i)));
            feed.setMyFiles(previewsPath [i]);

        //feed.setMyFiles(previewsPath [i]);
       // intarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(previewsPath[i]);
       // feed.setThumbnail(intarray[i]);
        os_versions.add(feed);
    }

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // ListView
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    //Grid View
    // recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2,1,false));

    //StaggeredGridView
    // recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2,1));

    mAdapter = new CardViewDataAdapter(os_versions);       
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
  }
}
```

**Model class**

```
public class FeedProperties {

 private String title;
 private String myfiles;
 private int thumbnail;

 public String getTitle() {
    return title;
 }

 public String getMyFiles() {
    return myfiles;
 }

 public void setMyFiles(String myfiles) {
    this.myfiles = myfiles;
 }

 public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
 }

 public int getThumbnail() {
    return thumbnail;
 }

 public void setThumbnail(int thumbnail) {
    this.thumbnail = thumbnail;
 }
}
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class CardViewDataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder> {

 private static ArrayList<FeedProperties> dataSet;

 public CardViewDataAdapter(ArrayList<FeedProperties> os_versions) {
    dataSet = os_versions;
 }

 @Override
 public CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    //create a new view
     View itemLayoutView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.card_view, null);

    //create ViewHolder
     ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(itemLayoutView);
     return viewHolder;
  }

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewDataAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    FeedProperties fp = dataSet.get(i);

    viewHolder.tvVersionName.setText(fp.getTitle());
    viewHolder.tvmyfilesName.setText(fp.getMyFiles());
    viewHolder.iconView.setImageResource(fp.getThumbnail());
    viewHolder.feed = fp;
 }

 @Override
 public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
 }

 // inner class to hold a reference to each item of RecyclerView
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvVersionName;
    public TextView tvmyfilesName;
    public ImageView iconView;

    public FeedProperties feed;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);

        tvVersionName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvVersionName);
        tvmyfilesName = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.tvmyfilesName);
        iconView = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.iconId);

        itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondPage.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "os version is: " + feed.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
     }
   }
}

      ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String s : pathToFiles.list()) {
            filePaths.add(s);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < previewsPath.length; i++) {
            FeedProperties feed = new FeedProperties();
            feed.setThumbnail(Drawable.createFromPath(filePaths.get(i)));
            feed.setMyFiles(previewsPath [i]);

        //feed.setMyFiles(previewsPath [i]);
        //intarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(previewsPath[i]);
        //feed.setThumbnail(intarray[i]);
        os_versions.add(feed);
        }
```

Comment: Try something like this...

ArrayList<String> filePaths;

//populate filePaths with your list of file paths. 

feed.setThumbnail(Drawable.createFromPath(filePaths.get(i)));

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < previewsPath.length; i++) {
            FeedProperties feed = new FeedProperties();
            ArrayList<String> filePaths;
            feed.setThumbnail(Drawable.createFromPath(filePaths.get(i)));

            feed.setMyFiles(previewsPath [i]);
           // intarray[i] = Integer.parseInt(previewsPath[i]);
           // feed.setThumbnail(intarray[i]);
            os_versions.add(feed);

Comment: more like this...

ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();

for (String s : pathToFiles.list()) {

filePaths.add(s);

}


for (int i = 0; i < previewsPath.length; i++) {  

FeedProperties feed = new FeedProperties();

feed.setThumbnail(Drawable.createFromPath(filePaths.get(i))); 

feed.setMyFiles(previewsPath [i]); 

}

Comment: ok trying now. thanks

Comment: ok i tried that see above. i also added my FeedProperties.class as it shows this now. setThumbnail (int) in FeedProperties can not be applied to android.graphics.drawable.Drawables

Comment: ok added CardViewDataAdapter.class too, i will also add the full MainCardActivity.class

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using the picasso library? here's a tutorial http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-bitmaps-efficiently.html. There's also a link in this tutorial showing how to use picasso and recyclerview. And here's a link to Picasso's web page http://square.github.io/picasso/. Good luck

Comment: tried that too.  its a very good library but I find no working examples of how to do this as the tutorial code link is dead.  and the links you posted don't actually get the images off the sdcard,  they use a string array of .drawables from your resources.